# Duplicates of canonical questions that have not been migrated from meta.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

There appear to be several canonical questions that are only available on meta.stackexchange.com.

e.g.:

- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)
- [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)
- [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

That makes sense; there is no need to duplicate these questions on each meta.

However these questions get re-asked a lot. So far the new questions could be closed as duplicates, but with the old questions on another site, this close reason is no longer available, since you can only select questions from the current site when closing as duplicate.

(One such question where I was unable to select the correct duplicate was [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253237/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)
but the question has now been removed by its author)

So, what would be the best way to resolve this?

- should we wait until the first new user re-asks such a question on this site, then use that first question as the new canonical duplicate? This has the drawbacks that these questions are usually very poorly formulated.
- should we migrate new duplicates to meta.stackexchange.com, only to close them directly afterwards? Seems like a lot of busywork just to close a question.
- should we keep a copy of these canonical questions here just for closing?
- should we allow selection of questions from meta.stackexchange.com when voting to close a question as duplicate?

I think the last option is clearly the best here. So I would like to request that the dialog to close as duplicate includes questions from this meta.stackoverflow.com as well as from meta.stackexchange.com, or at least accepts urls from stackexchange when entered manually.

Comment: Just answer the questions and reference the duplicate on MSE for further information and points of view.

Comment: I'm sure the last point has been raised on MSE, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229870/could-we-allow-child-meta-questions-to-be-closed-as-duplicates-of-meta-se-ones @ChrisF?

Comment: @Bart - yes and no. Yes in that it addresses the same issue, but no in that I'm sure I commented on the one I was thinking of.

Comment: Perhaps we should close this question now as a duplicate of the other one? :)

Comment: *> " Just answer the questions and reference the duplicate"*. Answering the question each time takes a lot more effort than voting to close though, unless you write a link-only answer. And that effort seems wasted if there is nothing to add that is not already explained in the canonical answer. I suppose you could just copy-paste the content of the canonical answer, but that seems sub-optimal.

Comment: This is definitely a point of 'pain' resulting from the migration process. But it's a point of pain that all the per-site Meta sites have, and I think the suggestion @Bart made is the best thing to do.