# Numbers in square brackets increase when adding images

Tags: bug, images

I was just writing a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25783231/1888983) which included both images and matrix indexing with `matrix[i][j]`, when I noticed my `j` was changing every time I updated an image in the post.

I'm assuming there's some script that handles changing of referenced images in square brackets automatically (e.g. `![Image description][6]`), and think it needs to be made more conservative if possible. Perhaps references should remain static to avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: Reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154936/164403) on the über-meta.

Comment: @FredericHamidi You might not use the word "über-meta" since not all people here are German. Just post the link

Comment: @msrd0, I did not coin that term, it has already been in use for a while now. I don't use it for its German prefix, but because "super-meta" and "hyper-meta" are modifier key combinations on some platforms.

Comment: @msdr0 For what it's worth, Americans at least are very familiar with the use of "über-" as a prefix. [Wiki suggests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cber) the same is true of English-speakers generally.

Comment: No, Americans spell it "uber". Germans spell it "über". When Americans see "über" they think it's the name of a heavy-metal band.

Comment: Also appearing: big meta, meta-meta, overmeta.  (Now we're getting meta about referring to metas.)

Comment: @Gabe On the off chance that you're not making a Spın̈al Tap-esqe joke: Those are spelled the same. The addition of a diacritic doesn't create a distinct letter in English (or in German, for that matter).

Comment: @AirThomas: It was indeed a joke. I would suggest that for Americans the two words are the same (most Americans know how to type an umlaut), but in German it's actually different. The umlaut changes the pronunciation and `ü` collates as `ue`, and if you couldn't type `ü` you would type `ueber`.

Comment: @Gabe I stand corrected re: ze Germans. Was going off the shared alphabet.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: StackMetaflow?

Comment: @AirThomas [enwp.org/WP:DAW](http://enwp.org/WP:DAW)

Comment: +1 the question because of the meta-uber comments.

Answer (score 11):

As per advice in this [Q](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253249/duplicates-of-canonical-questions-that-have-not-been-migrated-from-meta-stackexc), I copyed my answer from the [referenced duplicate on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154936/adding-a-new-link-to-a-post-messes-up-indexes-in-square-brackets-in-code-already):

> I had the same problem and whilst investigating this, Tim Stone kindly
>   pointed me to this Question in the [tavern (starting here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1697915#1697915)).
>
> He explained this "is an existing bug" and "the problem is mostly that
>   the editor piece is (mostly) unaware of the parser behaviour, so it
>   doesn't have the context to make smart decisions most of the time."
>   <sup>He would also look into "how difficult it would be to submit a
>   patch to PageDown to fix it here shortly" (yippie)!</sup>
>
> **Current workaround:**          Don't use the editor's hyperlink function (both button and keyboard shortcut
>   <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).          Instead, add the links
>   manually:
>
> - `[text](url)`
> - `<a href="url">text</a>`
> - or url-list: `[text][url_number]`         with accompanying
>
>   ```
>     [url_number]: url
>   ```
>
>   (at the bottom of the answer)
>
> Hope this helps for now!
>
> [image: Kitten draws red freehand-circle around important things in life]

Comment: `[url][]` followed by `[url]: url` works as well

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: maybe if you'd check the date of the original post.. you'd see that it's date (Dec 21 '13) *pre-dates* april 2014. So when I created that image, XP was still officially supported. And I'll have a lick (but am not going to take the bait): XP is still supported until april 2019 for whoever pays (or knows a special trick, something with POS). Just as my favorite w2k was 'supported' until (almost) 2013 (if ya knew how). *but Thanks for half the vote* `:)`